# ImageView Intersect Not being detected

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, rect, intersect

I am trying two different ways to detect an intersection and neither is working. I followed other threads but for some reason neither way is working! Can anyone help? This is my first attempt at this.

Activity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.graphics.Rect;


public class gameScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Global variable declarations
    Button quit_button;
    Button pause_button;
    String aviChoice;
    String aviMF_choice;
    ImageView aviCharacter, aviBase;
    Handler handler0 = new Handler();
    Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    Handler handler2 = new Handler();
    Handler handler3 = new Handler();
    float aviHeightLimit, jumpDeltaY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gamescreen);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
        {
            aviChoice = extras.getString(aviMF_choice);
        }

        jumpDeltaY = 10;
        aviCharacter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.aviCharacter_img);
        final Rect aviCharacterRect = new Rect();
        aviCharacter.getHitRect(aviCharacterRect);
        aviBase = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.aviBase_img);
        final Rect aviBaseRect = new Rect();
        aviBase.getHitRect(aviBaseRect);

        aviHeightLimit = aviBase.getY() - 150;
        aviCharacter.setY(aviBase.getY() - 25);

        aviBase.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bouncebase);
        if(aviChoice.equals("male"))
        {
            aviCharacter.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.avimstandard);
        }
        if(aviChoice.equals("female"))
        {
            aviCharacter.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.avifstandard);
        }


        //Runnables ================================================================================
        Runnable aviJumping = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(aviCharacter.getY() < aviHeightLimit)
                {
                    jumpDeltaY = -jumpDeltaY;
                }
                if(Rect.intersects(aviBaseRect, aviCharacterRect))
                {
                    Log.i("test", "intersection detected old");
                    jumpDeltaY = -jumpDeltaY;
                }
                if(aviCharacterRect.intersect(aviBaseRect))
                {
                    Log.i("test", "intersection detected new");
                    jumpDeltaY = -jumpDeltaY;
                }
                aviCharacter.setY(aviCharacter.getY() + jumpDeltaY);
                Log.i("test", ""+Rect.intersects(aviCharacterRect,aviBaseRect));
                handler0.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        };
        handler0.postDelayed(aviJumping,100);
        //==========================================================================================
    }
```